# Replace specific tags in xml in unix

Tags: xml, perl, unix, awk, ed

I would like to replace specific values (Not for all elements).
 Here all are having same Background_color, but i do not want to replace Background_color for only specific one. How can we implement?
This is just a sample code.(I would have list of skin names in file for which i should not replace the Background_color)

```
            <Skins>
             <skin>
               <att name="Name" value="sknLblG3S3" type="String"/>
               <att name="WidgetType" value="Label" type="String"/>
               <att name="Background_color" value="228,221,213" type="RGB"/>
            <skin>
            <skin>
              <att name="Name" value="name" type="String"/>
              <att name="WidgetType" value="Label" type="String"/>
              <att name="Background_color" value="228,221,213" type="RGB"/>
            <skin>
            <skin>
              <att name="Name" value="sknLblG3S5" type="String"/>
              <att name="WidgetType" value="Label" type="String"/>
              <att name="Background_color" value="228,221,213" type="RGB"/>
            <skin>
            <skins>
```

Comment: I would like to iterate through the whole xml file.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Whilst I'm normally keen on people trying to do it themselves, when it comes to `XML` that's often going off in completely the wrong direction anyway, and trying to hack it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML is in fact valid (your sample isn't - I've had to fix some of the tags by hand) - Then you should use an XML parser. As you've tagged perl, I'll assume a perl answer is acceptable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile( 'your_file.xml' );

#find and iterate all the 'skin' elements. 
foreach my $skin ( $twig->get_xpath('//skin') ) {
    #Check the 'att' element with these particular attributes. E.g. Name, sknLblG3S3
    if ( $skin->get_xpath('./att[@name="Name"][@value="sknLblG3S3"]') ) {
        #select the att with a name of 'Background_Colour' 
        my $bg_att = $skin->get_xpath( './att[@name="Background_color"]', 0 );
        #modify the attribute 'value'. 
        $bg_att->set_att( 'value', "123,456,789" );
    }
}

#set output formatting - note, this can break with certain XML elements, which you don't seem to have. 
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print;
```

You could iterate the `att` elements with `$skin -> children()` if you find it easier to read, and the `att` method in XML::Twig reads attributes. I feel `xpath` is clearer in this example though.

(You can also probably do a more complicated xpath statement to match children/siblings, but I'm not sure that'd help readability).

Comment: Actually this is what our xml file would like, (We are using this for our mobile based applications). Its just that I have reduced the number of att tags. xml file is one file and another file for having names of some specific skin names. So how do i take the name for another file and compare if this  name is the one in loop??

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and you should probably ask it separately. But do double check if your XML is valid in your source sample - because what you quoted isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, you could try this

```
awk -F"=?\"?[ ]*" 'BEGIN{replace="sknLblG3S3"; newcolor="0,0,0"}
                   $4=="Name"{name=$6}
                   ($4=="Background_color" && match(replace, name))
                      {gsub(/value="[0-9,]*"/, "value=\""newcolor"\"");}
                   {print;}' inputFile
```

You have to define two variables in the `BEGIN`-block:

- `replace`: The skin name(s) to be replaced, e.g., `replace="name,sknLblG3S3"`
- `newcolor`: The new background color

Comment: ... but you really shouldn't, because regex based parsing of XML is a filthy habit.